# Class cast exception while using WindowManager in Android

Tags: android

My code to get the screen height dynamically:

```
Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
```

Error:
    Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
Complete log cat: http://pastebin.com/8zUNFUYn

Edit:
Changed code to this:

```
Display display =  (activity).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
```

Worked but, gave a new error that is display.getSize(size) is not a method. Is that API depreceated?

Comment: always put full logcat here..........

Comment: unfortunately your logs dont tell anything about **ClassCastException**....

Comment: @Waqas http://pastebin.com/YwEq3BKj

Comment: com.crumbs.util.UserListAdapter.UserListAdapter.getView(UserListAdapter.java:94) is the line that has a problem.  please post it.

Comment: getSize is only available on api 13 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Context

is base class for both Application and Activity. Since your a getting an Application with `getContext()`, casting it to `Activity` causes the `ClassCastExecption`.

Answer (score 1):

replace your line with this :

if you are using this code inside activity then use this:

```
Display display = this.getContext().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: I used this: Display display = ((Activity) this.getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); And still got the same error.

Comment: getContext() isn't returning the `Activity` - you'd probably be better off if you included some code to show how your adapter is built and how you create it in your `Activity`. Are you using `#getApplicationContext()` to obtain the `Context` you store in it?